# Testing the cache hits for Flask-Cache

Tags: python, caching, flask, flask-cache

I am using `cache.memoize` to memoize a function with Flask-Cache.  How can I get the cache key which got set in the decorated function?  How can I test that the function is cached during testing?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.cache import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

@cache.memoize(timeout=10)
def get_news(nid, lang=None):
    return nid, lang

@app.route('/news/<str:nid>')
def news(news_id):
    return 'News: ' + get_news(news_id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `memoize`, the cache key is generated behind the scenes and should never need to be accessed manually.  Flask-Cache is handling caching and retrieving the result of the function for you.  But if you're interested in how Flask-Cache does it, you can [look at the source](https://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache/blob/1c60076b6d4c2df0ac1de54c59e63b4f780cecbc/flask_cache/__init__.py#L374).  It is a hash of the function name, arguments, and a uuid.

You shouldn't need to test cache hits, because Flask-Cache is already tested.  You should test your own code, not library code.  But if you're interested in how Flask-Cache does it, you can [look at the tests](https://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache/blob/1c60076b6d4c2df0ac1de54c59e63b4f780cecbc/test_cache.py).  It memoizes a function that returns the current time, then checks if the return is the same after sleeping.